# [video.js]Hide Control Bar at the beginning with autoplay

Tags: html5-video

I am using version 4.0.3 of video.js. What can I change in the code to hide the Control Bar at the beginning with autoplay?

Answer (score 1):

Just fire this script off. Remember to put the ID of your script in there:

```
// When the player has finished initialising
videojs("your_player_id_here").ready(function(){
    // Add a function to the play event
    this.on('play', function(){
        // The fade is animated with CSS, so set it going.
        $('.vjs-control-bar').removeClass('.vjs-fade-in').addClass('vjs-fade-out');
    });

});
```